# Click on UIButton outside table view change in tableview cell text

Tags: swift, button, tableview

I am new in IOS and i want to create a table view and a `UIButton` outside from tableView in swift.

I want to click on a `UIButton` and then change text of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: If the functionality is to change particular cell data so you have to make the button in the cell also the class for the cell.
You can provide some sketches that will help us to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would create new `UIViewController`. In this view controller create `UITableView` property and `UIButton` property and in init of view controller I would create new `UITableView` and assign to this property, same for `UIButton`.

Implement `tableViewDelegate` and `tableViewDatasource` methods.

In `viewDidLoad()` you need to make some layouting. For example fit table view in first half, and button under table view.

In button action you can change your dataModel on which `tableView` is rendered. (In method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`)

After all you need is call `tableView.reloadData()` and method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is triggered and re-render table based on updated datamodel.

**Minimal code example**
In this code example, UIButton is not under tableView and is in navigationBar. Also whole controller is subclass of UITableViewController instead of adding tableView to UIViewController. I just want to make it simple as possible.

```
//
//  MasterViewController.swift
//  stackOverflow
//
//  Created by Jakub Prusa on 14.07.17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Jakub Prusa. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var dataModel = ["AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD",]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(modifyDataModel(_:)))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

    }

    // MARK: - Button action
    func modifyDataModel(_ sender: Any) {
        dataModel[2] = "xx_CCC_xx"
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataModel.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel!.text = dataModel[indexPath.row] 
        return cell
    }
}
```